# Why openFd(filename) don't work with String?

Tags: java, android

```
private void startSound(String filename) throws IOException{
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filename);
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
case R.id.addForLearning:

        break;
    case R.id.music:

        String words = mainDataTextView.getText().toString();

        String con = "voice/"+words+".mp3";

        try {
            startSound(con);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
```

Why S`tring in openFd(filename)` don't work? I got `FileNotFoundException`. If I type `openFd("voice/song.mp3")` all working, but it don't right for me.

Comment: What is your current working directory when you execute that code?

Comment: How is `startSound()` called?  With what value is it called?  Can you post that code please?

Comment: @pathfinderelite I update case. startSound() called in method OnClick. value is String.

Comment: If you log the `filename` string, is its value what you expect (e.g. "voice/song.mp3")?

Comment: @pathfinderelite yes, exactly same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wager quite a bit that the string that you get from your textview isn't trimmed of whitespaces.

Try

```
String words = mainDataTextView.getText().toString();
String trimmedWords = words.trim();
String con = "voice/"+trimmedWords+".mp3";
```

Also, if this is not correct, could you print what `words` contains?

Comment: Thank you!! You are my savior.